# Mobile Push Notification using Web App

Tags: android, iphone

1- I want to write a simple web app (not native) used to send my clients news via push notification on ios, android, etc.
I found pusher.com, but the demo is not working.
It could be great if I can link it to my rss url, so they can get notified whenever a new record is added.
2- I want to add shortcut of my app on client devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GCM for android, and APNS for iOS, and there are many tutorials of these. Especially, iOS very strict rule for push notification, or your app will be rejected.